# How to monitor EMC VNXe3200?

Tags: monitoring, storage-area-network, performance-monitoring, system-monitoring

Currently, I'm using Solarwind to monitor my system, but VNXe can not. Any solution to monitor this? I just get a notification via email or SMS when my disk or array is failed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair I did not have any VNX in my production environment but I found this:
https://www.logicmonitor.com/support/monitoring/storage-systems/emc-vnxclariion-san/ Should be a valid way to setup monitoring.